# Image upload failed- file not writable

Tags: image, upload, permissions

Trying to upload images and get the following error

Upload failed for "filename". The error message was "Error uploading the file: The folder "/var/www/html/imgs/logos/" is not writable"

Answer (score 3):

On the **server**, check:

- if the folder exists?
- Check the folder permissions are set to 777 (could probably reduce to 755)

Within **Craft**:

In: **Settings** > **Assets** > **Asset Sources** - make sure **File System Path** and **URL** fields, have no leading forward slashes e.g.

```
imgs/logos/
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The folder exist and craft asset settings are correct.

Where do I change file permissions?

Comment: Of course. From within your FTP client, you should be able to right click on the folder and choose "file permissions". Normally you could tick some checkboxes or just type the chmod numbers e.g. 777

Comment: Changed permissions in FTP client. Still getting the same error.